# Temporary redirect during server maintenance (https to http)

Tags: apache, redirect, ssl

I'm coming to you because I'm stuck on the following problem:
I have a website, hosted on a server on which I will be doing messy maintenance stuff (understand I'm not sure what I'm doing so I might crash everything).
I'd like to temporarily redirect all the traffic to a simle page stating the website is undermaintenance and will be back soon.

So this page must be hosted on another server, since mine will be down.
To make matters more complicated, I have an ssl certificate on my whole website, so most of my users have the https adress memorized in their browser (and that's also what's memorized by google).
I've tried hosting the simple page on a free hosting, and also on microsoft azure (because I already have an account for another web-project). However, i've encountered the same problem in both cases: the users coming to the website see big red flags from thei browsers, saying that the connexion isn't private. (ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID)

What would be the proper way to proceed and redirect my users in a smooth way?

Thanks in advance!
Rouli

Comment: Have you found out something?